# Error reading my csv file in class in Java Application

Tags: java, xml, csv

I need to read a sample.csv file from the same class as my main. 
Below you can see the structure.

[image]
This is my code but when I run it it gave me the error that the sample.csv is not find!

```
public int convertFile(String csvFileName, String xmlFileName,
                    String delimiter) {
        int rowsCount = -1;
        BufferedReader csvReader;
        try {
            Document newDoc = domBuilder.newDocument();
            // Root element
            Element rootElement = newDoc.createElement("XMLCreators");
            newDoc.appendChild(rootElement);
            // Read csv file
            csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFileName));
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("sample.csv"));
            //CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(csvReader);
            String[] nextLine;
            int line = 0;
            List<String> headers = new ArrayList<String>(5);
            while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
....
```

Can anyone suggest me what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without relative or absolute path, it is directly related to the "current" directory. So it does NOT matter so much that the **.csv** file is in a certain package, **but it does matter that when the application is started the "working" directory is exactly the directory that contains the file.**
You are using Eclipse, go to see the Run Configuration *(Run menu -> Run Configurations ...)* used to launch the application, Arguments tab.
[image: See Attachment for same]

you can get path like this.

```
URL url = YourClassName.class.getResource("sample.csv");
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(url.getFile());
```